# WAS 8.5.5.9 cannot start webapplication because of SRVE0303E

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, websphere-8

I have the following problem:

In my web.xml I define how to serve pictures like so:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

On Tomcat this works fine but on IBM Websphere 8.5.5.9 I get the following error:

> "SRVE0303E: Servlet name for the servlet mapping *.css could not be found."

On another site I already found a solution for this issue (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=5f4420ba-0754-43fe-8c87-91acc588d9fc) so I also created the ibm-web-ext.xml exactly the same as in their solution but the error still persists.

Does anyone know what I could do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem, thanks to @MigratedPigeon because he got me thinking about the class of my default servlet.

A tomcat server has a default servlet, the class for tomcats default servlet is

> org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet

Websphere on the other hand does not have a default servlet, thats why I get the error "Servlet Name could not be found".

As in the answer I linked in the original question, static file serving can be activated by websphere by using the web-ext.xml file but that still did not solve the issue of my web.xml file having a "default" servlet.

In our application we use spring, so in the end I replaced the default servlet in web.xml with springs dispatcher servlet and now my web.xml file is valid for both, tomcat and websphere.

Answer (score 0):

you should also mention this in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>your servlet class</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Servlet mapping is done based on the value mentioned in the "" tags and respective servlet will be called.