# Servlet mapping not found error while deploying JAX RS application to web sphere 8.5

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, web-services, websphere

I am new to web services. have developed a simple rest web svc  in java using Eclipse, Tomcat following this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfEUDAHgrGQ). Application successfully runs on Tomcat but when i deploy it to IBM WebSphere 8.5.5. It deploys successfully but fails to start. I know its something with my Web.xml so i am adding it for rectification. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760975/was-8-5-5-9-cannot-start-webapplication-because-of-srve0303e) but to no avail.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>wstest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Java WS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    
  
  <init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>book</param-value>
  </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Java WS</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  
  
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Web Sphere log generated when i try to start application is:-

```
0000112c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: TestWS_war  Application build level: Unknown
0000112c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationHelper 
constructServletMappings SRVE0303E: Servlet name for the servlet mapping /* could not be found.
0000112c DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, TestWS.war, of application, TestWS_war.ear/deployments/TestWS_war, 
failed to start
0000112c ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, TestWS_war
0000112c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: TestWS_war
0000112c ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: TestWS_war
0000112c CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=TestWS_war in BLA 
WebSphere:blaname=TestWS_war failed to start.
0000112c MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: 
WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=svrNode01,
version=8.5.5.0,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,
cell=svrNode01Cell,spec=1.0 
because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: 
SRVE0303E: Servlet name for the servlet mapping /* could not be found.
```

I have tried both Class loading options Parent First and Parent Last but to no avail.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and provide the text of any relevant server log errors?

Comment: @andrewjames Sir log added please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving the error that "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer" is missing in the Class path. Because of which the application is not starting.

See the version of Jersey that is compatible with WAS 8.5.5? (I think it's Jersey 1.x). The corresponding library needs to be used.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I checked. There wasnt default application however, i stopped all installed applications and changed context root to testWS further i created another package inside book as book.ws and in web.xml changed /* to /ws/*. however, it threw same error that servlet mapping /ws/* could not be found.

Comment: Go to the Admin console and see the context root of the webapp (Test_ws)

Comment: Sir i have checked its TESTWS

Comment: Have updated the answer, it's not due to the DefaultWebApplication. it's because of the incorrect servlet class which worked in Tomcat but not in WAS

Comment: I used web.xml from your answer changing url pattern to /book/* but application didnt run on development environement on tomcat.

Comment: further, the jar containing org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is avail in the class path. can you give me complete web.xml? what will happen with init-param tags etc?

Comment: Here is the complete example - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=djrwa-getting-started-jax-rs